# VBA - Textbox value format

Tags: excel, vba

I have some problem with formatting in Textbox value and checking condition

[image]

1. Each textbox after entering will auto format in percent.
2. When finishing entering the last textbox, it will check if total sum is equal to 1.

I can work on the 1st one. However, when checking sum of three somehow I cannot format the value as in value/double. Value I obtain from the 3 textboxes are still in string. I tried to convert but not success.

Please see if there is anything wrong with my code

```
Private Sub Land_Prob1_AfterUpdate()
On Error Resume Next
If Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1 <= 100 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value = Format(Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value / 100, "Percent")
ElseIf Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1 > 100 Or Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1 < 0 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1 = "0.00%"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Land_Prob2_AfterUpdate()
On Error Resume Next
If Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2 <= 100 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2.Value = Format(Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2.Value / 100, "Percent")
ElseIf Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2 > 100 Or Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2 < 0 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2 = "0.00%"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Land_Prob3_AfterUpdate()
Dim x1, x2, x3
On Error Resume Next
If Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3 <= 100 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3.Value = Format(Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3.Value / 100, "Percent")
ElseIf Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3 > 100 Or Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3 < 0 Then
    Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3 = "0.00%"
End If

'Check if total probability equal 100
If Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value <> "" And Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2.Value <> "" Then
    x1 = Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value
    x1 = CDbl(x1)
    x2 = Form_Simulation.Land_Prob2.Value
    x2 = CDbl(x2)
    x3 = Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3.Value
    x3 = CDbl(x3)
    If x1 + x2 + x3 <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Total probability must be equal 100%. Please enter again"
        Form_Simulation.Land_Prob3 = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

No matter how I tried to convert, the value is still in string hence I cannot sum them up for condition checking

Thank you for reading

Comment: Besides the answer given below, change `Format(Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value / 100, "Percent")` to `Format(Val(Form_Simulation.Land_Prob1.Value) / 100, "0.00%")` BTW you also may want to check if a "number" was entered in the textbox and not some random text...

Comment: @SiddharthRout: thank you. Can you please clarify the last point "may want to check if a "number" ... " I am not really get your point.

Comment: What would happen if you type `PTQuoc` in `Land_Prob1`?

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to convert them to numbers without the percent sign?

Try it like this instead:

```
x1 = CDbl(Replace(x1, "%", ""))
```

Comment: So format(value, "percent") does not convert the value into percent? It just leave it as string with % sign at the end? OMG